# Bicep deployment of Azure Machine Learning Workspace fails due to incorrect region

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I am currently writing a bicep template for deploying machine learning workspaces. I've run into a strange issue where it denies deployment due to incorrect location:

```
{"error":{"code":"LocationNotAvailableForResourceType","message":"The provided location 'northeurope' is not available for resource type 'Microsoft.MachineLearning/Workspaces'. List of available regions for the resource type is 'southcentralus,westeurope,southeastasia,japaneast,westcentralus'."}}
```

My code for the deployment looks like so:

```
resource MLWorkspace 'Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces@2023-10-01' = {
  name: workspaceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    storageAccount: storageAccount.id
    keyVault: keyVault.id
    applicationInsights: applicationInsights.id
  }
  tags:{
    'BSD Ticket Reference': tag1
    Company: tag2
    Department: tag3
    Description: tag4
    Division: tag5
    Owner: tag6
    'Parent Project': tag7
    'Project ID':tag8
  }
}
```

After some checks, there's absolutely no way that the workspace truly can't be deployed in the North Europe region. Deployment to that region goes through without issue if it's done through the portal. I ran a Powershell command, and unsurprisingly it showed that a resource of the same type as I'm trying to deploy is indeed located in North Europe:

```
Name              : fewgdsgdf
ResourceGroupName : rg-TemplateTest-AzureAI-001
ResourceType      : Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces
Location          : northeurope
ResourceId        : /subscriptions/<subid>/resourceGroups/rg-TemplateTest-AzureAI-001/providers/Microsoft.MachineLearningServices/workspaces/fewgdsgdf
```

I tried switching up the API versions on my deployment, and that didn't work either. Could it be something on the Microsoft side of things?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It turns out it was, in fact, the API version that was wrong. For some reason, you can only deploy in that region on 2022-12-01-preview.